# why isn't this if then satement working?

Tags: java

```
public boolean search(int value) {
    search(root,value);


}

private boolean search(Node node, int value) {

    if (node == null) {return false;}
    else if(node.getValue() == value){return true;}
    else if (node.getValue() > value) { System.out.println("searching left" + node.getValue() + '>' + value); search(node.left,value);}
    else  if (node.getValue() < value)  { System.out.println("searching right" + node.getValue() + '<' + value); search(node.right,value);}


}
```

for some reason eclipse is telling me that I need a return type here even though I already have one. Adding a "return false" at the end to appease eclipse just makes it not return things when the if statements should return them.

Comment: What should happen if all the `if` statements are false?

Comment: Neither the first `search` nor all of the branches in the second have `return`s

Comment: they can't all be false. a value has to be either greater, less than, equal or null.

Comment: @namenotfound the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: Why are you saying that you have a return type here ? Clearly you are not returning anything in two cases of the private function, nor in the public function.  When you say that "eclipse is telling ", it'd be helpful to show us the message, the messages usually have more information than they're given credit for.  Additionally, you need to return something outside of your branches, even if you never get there.  In this case, you would get there because the greater than and less than cases are not returning anything, they'll run to the end of the private function.

Comment: *"they can't all be false. a value has to be either greater, less than, equal or null."* What about if `node.getValue()` returns something different each time?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you keep rolling back trivial edits, but don't do that. I've locked the post for the time-being. If you have questions about this, then [take it to Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a `return` statement if the `>` or `<` cases are reached.  You need to `return` what the corresponding recursive call returns in those 2 cases.

The compiler will still complain, because it won't realize that you've covered all possible cases; it doesn't consider values.  If you also turn the last case into `else` without a condition, then that will satisfy the compiler.

Also, in the top `search` method, return what the call to the other `search` method returns.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean search(int value) {
    search(root,value);

    // add a return here
}

private boolean search(Node node, int value) {
    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (node.getValue() == value) {
        return true;
    } else if (node.getValue() > value) {
        System.out.println("searching left" + node.getValue() + '>' + value);
        return search(node.left, value);
    } else {
        System.out.println("searching right" + node.getValue() + '<' + value);
        return search(node.right, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you return from your first function?

Answer (score 0):

if `node.getValue()` is greater than or less than `value` you print a message but don't return anything.

Did you mean to return the result of search in those cases?

```
private boolean search(Node node, int value) {
    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    } else if(node.getValue() == value){
        return true;
    } else if (node.getValue() > value) { 
        System.out.println("searching left" + node.getValue() + '>' + value); 
        return search(node.left,value);
    } else  if (node.getValue() < value)  { 
        System.out.println("searching right" + node.getValue() + '<' + value); 
        return search(node.right,value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly you don't have a return statement in the last 2 else if statements, but even putting a return statement in both of them won't completely solve the error.

When having a method with a return value there must always be a return value outside of an if statement or inside an else statement. (inside an else if won't work).

Basically the compiler has no way of knowing whether any of the if statements will be true. It needs to be guaranteed that one of the statements will be true and return a value.

This is true even if it follows the following pattern:

```
if (a == b)
    return true;
if (a > b)
    return false;
if (a < b)
    return true;
```

As a human we can understand that at least one of those statements will be true, but the compiler doesn't. If you know at least one of the statements will be true you can simply put a `return;` statement at the end knowing it will never be called.